# Django: 'Country' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

Whenever I try to access my model "Youtube" from django admin, it shows me this error. I am sensing I have messed it up in the `YoutubeAdmin`, inside the `getCountry` method. How can I solve this? Cannot find a way. It says  `model Youtube doesn't have a filed getCountry` in the error.

**My model :**

```
class Youtube(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    scrap_interval_hour = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    last_scrapped_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_feed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateField(
        auto_now_add=True)
    # Foriegn Key
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_date', )
```

**admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from fpn.models import Youtube
from datetime import timedelta

class YoutubeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, youtube=None):
        fields = super(YoutubeAdmin, self).get_fields(request, youtube)
        fields.remove('last_scrapped_datetime')

        if youtube:
            fields.remove('country')
        return fields

    model = Youtube
    list_per_page = 10
    list_display = ('link', 'is_feed',
                    'getCountry', 'last_scrapped_datetime')
    list_filter = ('country', 'is_feed', )

    def getCountry(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([coun.name for coun in obj.country.all()])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForeignKey` create many-to-one relation. This mean for one country you can have many Youtube objects. But not reverse, one Youtube object can have only one country.

So in your case you cannot query list of countries from youtube object. Since it has only one related country which you can access directly:

```
def getCountry(self, obj):
   return obj.country.name
```